# How do I remove double square brackets in ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

After converting sql query from mysql object to json format I am getting array and I want only integer part from the array. Please let me know how can I achieve that.

```
query = "select count(priority) from table_complaint"
data = ActiveRecord::Base.connection(query).to_json
result is [[55]]
```

After executing above query I am getting results as [[integer]]
Now I want only integer/float part from the above array. Please help me out

Comment: SQL is table based. When you do a raw query you get an ActiveRecord::Result instance and when you implicitly cast it to an array you get an array of arrays which represent rows and columns in the result set. The real question here is whats the actual problem that you're trying to solve and why do you think this is the way to solve it? https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Answer (score 0):

You could take the first element of the outer array, which will be the inner array, and then the first element of that.

```
[[55]][0][0]
```

You might find the MiniSQL gem to be useful, but I wonder why you do not:

```
data = TableComplaint.count
```